# Excel VBA - Merging cells based on duplicates search

Tags: excel, vba, merge, duplicates

I need help writing a VBA code to find duplicate values in one column and then merge cells based off that search. 
E.g:

```
France  6216    EDE 009789  Company A
France  6216    EDF 009790  Company A
France  6216    EDG 009791  Company A
Germany 6216    EDH 009792  Company B
```

Becomes:

```
France  6216    EDE EDF EDG 009789 009790 009791    Company A
Germany 6216    EDH         009792                  Company B
```

Its on a large spreadsheet where some dupes will have two but some could be as many as eight.
Can anyone help me?

Any questions please let me know.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Just one question: do you have any code to show us?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this macro,

```
Sub removeDupes()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Columns("A:E").Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Sheets.Add.Name = "newSheet"
    Sheets("newSheet").Cells(1, 1) = Cells(2, 1)
    Sheets("newSheet").Cells(1, 2) = Cells(2, 2)
    Sheets("newSheet").Cells(1, 3) = Cells(2, 3)
    Sheets("newSheet").Cells(1, 150) = Cells(2, 4)
    Sheets("newSheet").Cells(1, 255) = Cells(2, 5)
    j = 1
    k = 1
    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i + 1, 1) = Cells(i, 1) Then
            Sheets("newSheet").Cells(j, 3 + k) = Cells(i + 1, 3)
            Sheets("newSheet").Cells(j, 150 + k) = Cells(i + 1, 4)
            k = k + 1
        Else
            j = j + 1
            Sheets("newSheet").Cells(j, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1)
            Sheets("newSheet").Cells(j, 2) = Cells(i + 1, 2)
            Sheets("newSheet").Cells(j, 3) = Cells(i + 1, 3)
            Sheets("newSheet").Cells(j, 150) = Cells(i + 1, 4)
            Sheets("newSheet").Cells(j, 255) = Cells(i + 1, 5)
            k = 1
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 255 To 1 Step -1
        If Sheets("newSheet").Cells(1, i) = "" Then
            Sheets("newSheet").Columns(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Source:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Gowtham Shiva. Thanks a mil for your response. I get a syntax error when i try to run the above code. The data will have headers. I am very new to VBA coding. Can you advise how to adjust and resolve the above error? Again thanks for your assistance

Comment: @redmond358 I have modified the formula as you have headers. Please give a try

Comment: Sub removeDupes()
    Dim i As Long
    Columns("A:E").Sort key1:=Range("A1") order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes - This is the line highlighted

Comment: @redmond358 can you try now.. I have updated the code

Comment: Same syntax error with the 3rd line highlighted.. Im new to coding. Does the sheet name matter?

Comment: Is your data in columns A to E? or some other?

Comment: Its in A:E with headers

Comment: @redmond358 my bad.. While copy pasting the code some data truncated. Now it should work. Please try the new code

Comment: It opens a new blank worksheet called "newSheet" but the data remains unchanged in the original sheet. Appreciate you looking a this for me

Comment: @redmond358 yes, you will have the expected output only in the new sheet. The source will be left unchanged. Since you are moving row values to columns, you cannot update the source sheet

Comment: Ok that makes sense. The new sheet is blank though?

Comment: @redmond358 no it shouldnt be. It just works fine for me

Comment: Ok not sure what I'm doing wrong. New worksheet is coming up blank.

Comment: @redmond358 add the image of your source sheet to the question

Comment: I cant post images because I'm new to the site unfortunately. Source file is the same format as above with headers. Sorry for the inconvenience, again thanks for your help

Comment: @redmond358 checkout my images

Comment: I got this to work. Many thanks for all your effort Gowtham Shiva!

Comment: @redmond358 please mark my answer as correct. that would be the right way to tell "Thanks" !!